# How can I show the Adobe Reader toolbar having right panel collapsed when displaying a PDF in IE ActiveX control?

Tags: pdf, adobe, webbrowser-control, activexobject, adobe-reader

This is a foxpro application, but the question more about pdf parameters, so applies to .Net Webrowser control

```
this.ie1.navigate2(xurl + "#toolbar=1&zoom=100&navpanes=0&statusbar=0")
```

Is there any possibility to show the top toolbar, but have the right panel ( Export pdf , Convert , Create PDF and etc )  immediately collapsed without clicking on a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

PDF Open Parameters cannot control the right panel, only the left.

See further documentation here...
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf